# Login Errors not sure why

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm using a login with a scope to ensure that the user account is active. If the login fails how can i tell if it failed because the email was not matched or if the accounts wasn't activated?

Also, i didn't understand all of the documentation in the cakephp cookbooks, could you please look at my auth section in my components array?
The Email field in the html table and sql table are called 'AccountEmail'
The Password field in the html table and sql table are called 'AccountPassword'
The row in the sql table for active accounts is called 'AccountActive' and is an int type with a value of 0 if the user is not active and 1 if it is active.

```
'Auth' => array(
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Accounts', 'action' => 'login'),
        'authError' => 'You can\'t Access That Page',
        'authorize' => array('Controller'),
        'fields' => array('AccountEmail' => 'AccountEmail', 'AccountPassword' => 'AccountPassword'),
        'scope' => array('AccountActive' => '1')
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing which authentication handler to use and your fields configuration was wrong.

I'll assume you want to use a **form** to login:

```
/**
 * Auth component configuration
 */
public $components = array(
  'Auth'=> array(
    'logoutRedirect' => array(
      'controller' => 'Accounts', 
      'action' => 'login'
    ),
    'authError' => 'You can\'t Access That Page',
    'authorize' => array('Controller'),
    'authenticate' => array(
      'Form' => array(
        'fields' => array(
          'username' => 'AccountEmail',
          'password' => 'AccountPassword'
        ),
        'scope' => array('AccountActive' => '1')
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Do you know about how to detect why login failed?

Comment: It's not possible with the built in Form authentication. It only returns true or false.